# Exception : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, vsto

I am trying to call API using HTTPClient but i am getting the exception mentioned in the Title.

after a bit of research from stackoverflow i found that adding this line before service call solves the issue

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But the person did not explain the reason of this line and can this line case issues for any other part of the program.

note : the server i am connecting to uses https.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tls is the encryption method being used since the connection is https (secure). You original code was either not using a secure connection or using the wrong method (default) of encryption.

Comment: is using this line of code safe? and is there any alternative to this?

Comment: actually the code was working fine before this line and suddenly it stopped working.so i was wondering there may be some settings on server side which caused the issue.

Comment: The server could of been down or running slow so it didn't respond in a timely fashion.  There is nothing about this code that would make it unsafe.  It is a security question if the server allows un-secure connections or require secure connections.  The server may be using cookies and your PC has an invalid cookie.  Some times going to your IE and deleting cookies will get an application running.  The existing cookie may be unsecure and now that you changed code to use secure connection the cookie is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) article you will find that this property must be set before any call to HTTPS endpoint.

> This property selects the version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or
>   Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use for new connections
>   that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) scheme only;
>   existing connections are not changed. **Note that no default value is
>   listed for this property, on purpose.** The security landscape changes
>   constantly, and default protocols and protection levels are changed
>   over time in order to avoid known weaknesses. Defaults will vary
>   depending on individual machine configuration, and on which software
>   is installed, and on which patches have been applied.